When uploading an Excel Sheet into a Google Spreadsheet is not copying the working formula
This is the working formulas in Excel. It doesn't work in Google Sheets. How can I get it to work in Sheets?
=IFERROR(SUMIFS(ORDERS[QUANTITY],ORDERS[PRODUCT OR RAW MATERIAL NAME],RAWMATS[[#This Row],[RAW MATERIAL NAME]],ORDERS[ORDER TYPE],"PURCHASE",ORDERS[EXPECTED DATE],"<="&TD),"")


=IFERROR(SUMIFS(ORDERS!$B:$B, ORDERS!$A:$A, B2, ORDERS!$C:$C, "PURCHASE", ORDERS!$D:$D, "<="&TODAY()))

The problem is that Excel supports structured table references whereas Sheets does not. In order to accurately answer your question you would need to include a sample of your data in markdown format.
